# Looping a program to start again after finish checking

Tags: java, loops, exit, automata

I'm trying to make a program where the user would input a string over a and b, and the program would check whether it is accepted or not. Now i managed to make the program exit if the user input "exit", but i haven't been able to figure out how to loop the program and make it start again when it finished checking a string, asking the user to input again. How should i do it? Below is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Automata {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean keeprunning = true;
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your input");
    String input = inputScanner.next();
    char [] Inputted = input.toCharArray();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")){
        keeprunning = false;
        System.out.println("Exit now");
    }

    String stateA = "A";
    String stateB = "B";
    String stateC = "C";
    String stateD = "D";
    String stateE = "E";
    String stateF = "F";
    String currentState = "A";

    while(keeprunning){
    for (int i = 0; i < Inputted.length; i++){
        if (Inputted[i]=='a' && currentState.equals(stateA)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateA + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i]=='b' && currentState.equals(stateA)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateA + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateB)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateB + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateB)){
            currentState = "C";
            System.out.println(stateB + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateC);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i]== 'b' && currentState.equals(stateF)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateF + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateF)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateF + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateC)){
            currentState = "D";
            System.out.println(stateC + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateD);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateC)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateC + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateD)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateD + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateD)){
            currentState = "E";
            System.out.println(stateD + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateE);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateE)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateE + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateE)){
            currentState = "C";
            System.out.println(stateE + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateC);
        }   

    } if (currentState.equals(stateA) || currentState.equals(stateB) || currentState.equals(stateD) || currentState.equals(stateE)){
        System.out.println("Input accepted");
        keeprunning = false;
        break;
    } else if (currentState.equals(stateF) || currentState.equals(stateC)){
        System.out.println("Input not accepted");
        keeprunning = false;
        break;
    }

}
    }
```

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your `while` loop header to the top, just after `keeprunning` declaration:

```
Boolean keeprunning = true;
while(keeprunning){
...
```

And remove below code from `if-else` statement:

```
keeprunning = false;
break;
```

That should solve your stated problem

---

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Automata {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Boolean keeprunning = true;
while(keeprunning){
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your input");
    String input = inputScanner.next();
    char [] Inputted = input.toCharArray();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")){
        keeprunning = false;
        System.out.println("Exit now");
    }
    else{

    String stateA = "A";
    String stateB = "B";
    String stateC = "C";
    String stateD = "D";
    String stateE = "E";
    String stateF = "F";
    String currentState = "A";


    for (int i = 0; i < Inputted.length; i++){
        if (Inputted[i]=='a' && currentState.equals(stateA)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateA + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i]=='b' && currentState.equals(stateA)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateA + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateB)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateB + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateB)){
            currentState = "C";
            System.out.println(stateB + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateC);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i]== 'b' && currentState.equals(stateF)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateF + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateF)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateF + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateC)){
            currentState = "D";
            System.out.println(stateC + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateD);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateC)){
            currentState = "F";
            System.out.println(stateC + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateF);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateD)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateD + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateD)){
            currentState = "E";
            System.out.println(stateD + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateE);
        } 

        else if (Inputted[i] == 'a' && currentState.equals(stateE)){
            currentState = "B";
            System.out.println(stateE + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateB);
        } else if (Inputted[i] == 'b' && currentState.equals(stateE)){
            currentState = "C";
            System.out.println(stateE + " -- " + Inputted[i] + " --> " + stateC);
        }   

    } if (currentState.equals(stateA) || currentState.equals(stateB) || currentState.equals(stateD) || currentState.equals(stateE)){
        System.out.println("Input accepted");

    } else if (currentState.equals(stateF) || currentState.equals(stateC)){
        System.out.println("Input not accepted");
    }
}   

}
}
}
```

Comment: Ok i just edited the question. I mean loop the program as in when it output "Input Accepted" or "Input not accepted", it should show the "please enter your input" line in a new line and have the program run again until the user input "exit"

Comment: yes, I understand your problem. Just do as stated in my answer above, that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Real appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution for you would be to add a `while(true)` loop on all the code (at the start of `main()` )

the better solution will be to create a runnable thread with the logic of the program, and in the `main()` part run it.